# Solve Ito integral for continuous contributions to stock portfolio

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I'm following [Milevsky & Posner (2003)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228225821_A_Continuous-Time_Re-examination_of_the_Inefficiency_of_Dollar-Cost_Averaging) to model the value of a portfolio, $P$, assuming GBM (2) and a continuous contribution rate of $1$ (i.e. dollar-cost averaging):

$$
\mathrm d S_t/S_t = \mu \mathrm d t + \sigma \mathrm d B_t \iff S_t = S_0 \exp\left[ (\mu - \frac 1 2 \sigma^2)t + \sigma B_t \right] \tag{2}
$$

$$
P_T = S_T \int_0^T \frac{\mathrm dt}{S_t} \tag{6}
$$

Where $S_t$ is the stock price and $1/S_t$ is the amount of stock we can buy with $1.

$$
P_T = \int_0^T \hat S_\tau \mathrm d \tau
    = \int_0^T \exp\left[\mu \tau - \frac 1 2 \sigma^2 \tau  + \sigma \hat B_\tau \right] \mathrm d \tau \tag{8}
$$

where $\hat S_\tau \sim S_t$ and $\hat B_\tau \sim B_t$.

How can we solve this integral in terms of the normal/lognormal distribution?

How can we find, or approximate, the quintile function?  I want to use this to get quartiles & 95% CI for this investment strategy.

Are there any problems with modelling the problem this way, or is it important to use more complicated models such as stochastic volatility?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the solution may be:

$$
P_T = \frac 1 \mu \left( \exp \left[ \left(\mu-\frac 1 2 \sigma^2\right)T + \sigma\sqrt{T} \mathcal N \right] -1 \right)
$$

where $\mathcal N \sim \text{Normal}(0,1)$ so $P_T$ is a linear function of a LogNormal dsitribution.

This gives the correct result for the expected value and [the case where $\sigma = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2270738/3157), but I'm not sure how to actually derive it.

$$
\mathbb E[P_T] = P_{T\ \sigma=0} = \frac 1 \mu \left( e^{\mu T} - 1 \right)
$$